Recursively replacing or updating key value pairs in a nested dictionary
Say I have a dictionary like this:
mydict = {
  "name": "Bill", 
  "gender": "Male", 
  "facts": {"age": 20, "location": "England"}
}

so it contains another dictionary as a value. Now suppose I have this dictionary:
to_replace = {"name": "Billy Kidman", "gender": "Female"}

and I want to update mydict to reflect this new information. To do that I use
from dataclasses import replace
mydict = replace(mydict, **to_replace)

and this works, because now it looks like
mydict = {
  "name": "Billy Kidman", 
  "gender": "Female", 
  "facts": {"age": 20, "location": "England"}
}

Now suppose I want to update mydict with the following information:
to_replace_2 = {"name": "Billy Kidman", "gender": "Female", "age": 55}

Then I can't use replace as above, because age is not key of mydict but it's actually a key of a value. Python throws an error if I try to do this. How can I do this correctly? I have no freedom in the form of to_replace_2; it is how I wrote it above and I can't change that. Is there a way to make replace do what I want it to do, to find all the keys that need to be replaced no matter if they're nested and make the changes?

you need to write your own function that searches for each key recursively. There's nothing built-in that does this.

What if age would be a key that exists at several places in your nested structure, then what should happen? Should all of them be updated? The first one encountered in some order?

Try:
def replace(o, to_replace):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        common_keys = o.keys() & to_replace.keys()
        for k in common_keys:
            o[k] = to_replace[k]

        for v in o.values():
            replace(v, to_replace)

    elif isinstance(o, list):
        for v in o:
            replace(v, to_replace)


mydict = {"name": "Bill", "gender": "Male", "facts": {"age": 20, "location": "England"}}
to_replace_2 = {"name": "Billy Kidman", "gender": "Female", "age": 55}

replace(mydict, to_replace_2)

print(mydict)

Prints:
{'name': 'Billy Kidman', 'gender': 'Female', 'facts': {'age': 55, 'location': 'England'}}



Just write a separate method to update your dictionary.

The key is to first check for the value in your main dictionary and see if the value is an instance of a dict type. In that case, you recursively call _update() and your dictionary will be updated, if it is not.


Code
def _update(d, new_data):
    for key, value in new_data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            d[key] = _update(d.get(key, {}), value)
        else:
            d[key] = value
    return d


mydict = {"name": "Bill", "gender": "Male", "facts": {"age": 20, "location": "England"}}
to_replace = {"name": "Billy Kidman", "gender": "Female"}
to_replace_2 = {"name": "Billy Kidman", "gender": "Female", "age": 55}

print(_update(mydict, to_replace))
print(_update(mydict, to_replace_2))



Prints

{'name': 'Billy Kidman', 'gender': 'Female', 'facts': {'age': 20,
'location': 'England'}} {'name': 'Billy Kidman', 'gender': 'Female',
'facts': {'age': 20, 'location': 'England'}, 'age': 55}


Thanks but I think you missed that in to_replace_2 I don't have "facts", only the age part. Could you recheck?

Anytime you deal with recursion, it's important to define a base case.
In this case, if the dictionary passed in isn't a dictionary, we don't need to make any changes to it.
def my_update(d, new_data):
  if not isinstance(d, dict): return d

But, if it is a dict, then we can use a dictionary comprehension to update the value for each key from new_data. By using get rather than accessing with [] we can default to the existing value if the key is not found in new_data.
def my_update(d, new_data):
  if not isinstance(d, dict): return d
  return {
    k: my_update(new_data.get(k, v), new_data) 
    for k, v in d.items()
  }

The dictionary comprehension is syntactically very clean, but it also means that we don't modify the original dictionary.
We could even use a conditional expression though I'm not sure that improves readability.
def my_update(d, new_data):
  return d if not isinstance(d, dict) else {
    k: my_update(new_data.get(k, v), new_data) 
    for k, v in d.items()
  }

